# UISwipeGestureRecognizer not recognizing Ended State?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer

iOS developers/experts am mid-level iOS developer working an iOS Application, I want to trigger an action when I swipe (Left/Right) and release the hold. So am taking the support of UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded, But here the problem is the state UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded is recognized before releasing the hold. Here is my code

```
-(void)performAction:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    if(sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"RIGHT GESTURE");
    }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong ? any help/experience would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why you need end state ? any specific requirement ?

Comment: Kindly read my post

Comment: try enable this self.rightRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = YES

Comment: as per apple docs `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` is a discrete gesture not a continuous gesture so there is only one state and that is `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` so regarding your req you need to go either `UIPanGesture` or `UITouches` methods only.

Comment: @CodeChanger :- Thanks for your valuable comment

Comment: Always Welcome still you can refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896402/how-to-detect-end-of-uiswipegesturerecognizer it will help you to achieve what you required.